# Python вывод в Excel

Tags: python, файлы, excel

Как записать значения, вычисленные в скрипте, в файл `excell`?

```
__author__ = 'N1ZZE'

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math
import random

TL = [0,0,0,0]
TL1 = [0,0,0,0]
Y = []
T = []
M = []
L = 1
Sumt = 0
t = 0
C = 1
N = 0


Nrab = int(input('Please Input Nrab: '))
Tkc = float(input('Please Input Tkc: '))
a = float(input('Please Input a: '))

count = 0

while (count < 10):
    y = random.random()
    Y.insert(count,y)
    if (count<5):
        x = 1/y
        x1 = math.log(x)
        x = x1/a
        T.append(x)
    else:
        x = 1/Y[count]
        x1 = L * math.log(x)
        M.append(x1)
    count +=1
while (N < Nrab):

    t = T[0]
    k = 0
    if( t < TL[0] - Tkc):
        t = TL[0] + M[k]/C
    else:
        t = t + Tkc + M[k]/C

    TL1[0] = t

    if ((t < T[1]) and (t < T[2])):
        k = 0
    elif ( T[1] < T[2] ):
        k = 1
        t = T[1]
    else:
        k = 2
        t = T[2]

    if ( t < TL[1] - Tkc):
        t = TL[1] + M[k]/C
    else:
        t = t + Tkc + M[k]/C

    TL1[1] = t

    if (t > T[4]):
        k = 4
        t = T[4]

    if ( k==2 ):

        y1=random.random()
        y2=random.random()
        T[k]=T[k]+ math.log(1/y1)/a
        M[k]=L * math.log(1/y2)

        TL[1] = TL1[1]
        continue
    elif ( t < TL[2] - Tkc ):
        t = TL[2] + M[k]/C
    else:
        t = t + Tkc + M[k]/C

    TL1[2] = t

    if ( t > T[3] ):
        k = 3
        t = T[3]

    if ( k == 1 ):
        y1=random.random()
        y2=random.random()
        T[k]=T[k]+ math.log(1/y1)/a
        M[k]=L * math.log(1/y2)

        TL[1] = TL1[1]
        TL[2] = TL1[2]

        continue
    elif ( t< TL[3] - Tkc):
        t = TL[3] + M[k]/C
    else:
        t = t + Tkc + M[k]/C


    TL1[3] = t

    if ( k == 0):
        Sumt = Sumt + t - T[0]
        N = N + 1

    y1=random.random()
    y2=random.random()
    T[k]=T[k]+ math.log(1/y1)/a
    M[k]=L * math.log(1/y2)

    if ( k < 1 ):

        TL[0] = TL1[0]
        TL[1] = TL1[1]
        TL[2] = TL1[2]
        TL[3] = TL1[3]

    elif ( k == 3):

        TL[3] = TL1[3]

    elif ( k == 4):
        TL[2] = TL1[2]
        TL[3] = TL1[3]

    continue

Zkc=Sumt/N
print(Zkc)
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться пакетом [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Записать число в 1 строку и 1 колонку

```
num = 789789 #число, которое мы записываем

book = xlwt.Workbook()
row_index = 0 # номер строки, нумерация с 0
col_index = 1 # номер колонки, нумерация с 0

sheet1 = book.add_sheet("sheet0") # даем название таблице
row = sheet1.row(row_index)
row.write(col_index, num) # здесь сама запись числа
book.save("test.xls") # сохраняем в файл с названием test.xls
```

Более сложный пример с указанием названий столбцов и записью списка чисел

```
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("PySheet1")

cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

values = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20], [21,22,23,24,25]]

for row_index, row_values in enumerate(values):
    row = sheet1.row(row_index)
    for col_index, col in enumerate(cols):
        value = row_values[col_index]
        row.write(col_index, value)

book.save("test.xls")
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/03/24/creating-microsoft-excel-spreadsheets-with-python-and-xlwt/)

Comment: попытаюсь использовать его) спасибо)

Comment: Скажу из своего опыта: очень достойная вещь.

Comment: для меня сложно, я начинающий программист.
постараюсь справиться с ней

Comment: Да там все элементарно.

Comment: Отличная либа! Спасибо за информацию :)

Comment: @Vetedde, но вообще лучше было опубликовать свой собственный ответ, а не вносить правку в существующий. это относится и к ожидающей в данный момент подтверждения правке.

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin, спасибо, буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 1):

зависимо, какого, экселя, если xlsx - то просто xml-ку сгенерируйте, делов то

кстати, зачем было выкладывать сюда весь свой прекраснейший код? лучше бы выложили неудавшиеся попытки экспорта, может, так было бы легче вам помочь

P.S. если никакого функционала, кроме того, что выложен, не нужно, то в экселе/либрекалке это всё можно сделать куда проще и элегантнее

Comment: Нужно в xls.
я делал еще 1 while в котором выполнялся расчет, и записывал Zkc.
Но на деле получилось 24 одинаковых значений((
Сори за г***окод.
Пишу недавно(

Answer (score 1):

[csv](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV), не?

P.S. Дополненный код автора:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division

__author__ = 'N1ZZE'

import math
import random

Nrab = int(input('Please Input Nrab: '))
Tkc = float(input('Please Input Tkc: '))
a = float(input('Please Input a: '))

def func():
    TL = [0,0,0,0]
    TL1 = [0,0,0,0]
    Y = []
    T = []
    M = []
    L = 1
    Sumt = 0
    t = 0
    C = 1
    N = 0

    count = 0

    while count < 10:
        y = random.random()
        Y.insert(count, y)
        if count < 5:
            x = 1 / y
            x1 = math.log(x)
            x = x1 / a
            T.append(x)
        else:
            x = 1 / Y[count]
            x1 = L * math.log(x)
            M.append(x1)
        count += 1

    while N < Nrab:
        t = T[0]
        k = 0
        if  t < TL[0] - Tkc:
            t = TL[0] + M[k] / C
        else:
            t = t + Tkc + M[k] / C

        TL1[0] = t

        if t < T[1] and t < T[2]:
            k = 0
        elif T[1] < T[2]:
            k = 1
            t = T[1]
        else:
            k = 2
            t = T[2]

        if t < TL[1] - Tkc:
            t = TL[1] + M[k] / C
        else:
            t = t + Tkc + M[k] / C

        TL1[1] = t

        if t > T[4]:
            k = 4
            t = T[4]

        if k == 2:

            y1=random.random()
            y2=random.random()
            T[k]=T[k]+ math.log(1 / y1) / a
            M[k]=L * math.log(1 / y2)

            TL[1] = TL1[1]
            continue
        elif t < TL[2] - Tkc:
            t = TL[2] + M[k] / C
        else:
            t = t + Tkc + M[k] / C

        TL1[2] = t

        if t > T[3]:
            k = 3
            t = T[3]

        if k == 1:
            y1=random.random()
            y2=random.random()
            T[k]=T[k]+ math.log(1 / y1) / a
            M[k]=L * math.log(1 / y2)

            TL[1] = TL1[1]
            TL[2] = TL1[2]

            continue
        elif t < TL[3] - Tkc:
            t = TL[3] + M[k] / C
        else:
            t = t + Tkc + M[k] / C

        TL1[3] = t

        if k == 0:
            Sumt = Sumt + t - T[0]
            N = N + 1

        y1=random.random()
        y2=random.random()
        T[k]=T[k]+ math.log(1 / y1) / a
        M[k]=L * math.log(1 / y2)

        if k < 1:
            TL[0] = TL1[0]
            TL[1] = TL1[1]
            TL[2] = TL1[2]
            TL[3] = TL1[3]

        elif k == 3:

            TL[3] = TL1[3]

        elif k == 4:
            TL[2] = TL1[2]
            TL[3] = TL1[3]

        continue

    return Sumt, N

with open('workfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(24):
        Sumt, N = func()
        Zkc = str(Sumt / N)
        print(Zkc)
        f.write("{}\n".format(Zkc))
```

Comment: @Stan, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Nizze написал: Нужно в xls.
Для того, чтобы записать в xls необходимы дополнительно библиотеки (которых нет в Питоне в базовой установке). Я предлагаю воспользоваться форматом csv - это обычный текстовый файл, записать его не составит проблем, в Excel'е он откроется по умолчанию!

Comment: Ну, если в документе не нужна разбивка на листы и т.п. - csv будет хорошим (и безгеморройным) вариантом. Можно формировать его совсем руками, как в коде у Stan; можно работать с модулем csv, который вроде в дистрибутиве Питона сразу есть.